# NSIS: Detecting in uninstaller is a program working

Tags: nsis, uninstallation

Is it possible to determine in uninstaller script is a program (that should be uninstalled) working?

Comment: Do you mean running when you say working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to detect if your program is still running, you can use your knowledge of the programs internals to detect either a special window class or a mutex used by the program.

If you don't have anything other than exe name to go on, use one of the nsis plugins:

- http://nsis.sourceforge.net/LockedList_plug-in
- http://nsis.sourceforge.net/KillProc_plug-in
- http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Processes_plug-in
- http://nsis.sourceforge.net/FindProcDLL_plug-in